# Proving $| \text{Tr}[AB] | \leq \text{Tr}[ |AB| ]$ for $A,B \in \text{Pos}(V)$

Tags: inequality, trace, positive-semidefinite, hermitian-matrices

I came across an inequality for (finite dimensional) positive semi-definite operators and I tried to prove it, but I falied. Therefore, I hope some of you have a hint for me, what I missed.

Before I start, I give the definition of what is meant by $|A| := \sqrt{A^*A}$, where $A^*$ is transposing the matix $A$ and taking the element-wise coplex conjugate.
As this question occurres in in connection with a physical problem I hope that it is ok to use Dirac's BraKet notation.

Suppose now $A,B \in \text{Pos(V)}$, where $V$ is some finite-dimensional vector space. I want to show that
$| \text{Tr}[AB] | \leq \text{Tr}[AB]  $
holds.

In my approach to prove this statement, I used that every positive operator is Hermitian and can be diagonalized, $A = \sum_i \lambda_i |v_i\rangle \langle v_i |$ and $B = \sum_j \mu_j | u_j \rangle \langle u_j |$, where $\{v_i\}$ and $\{u_j\}$ are bases, consisting of eigenvectors of $A$ and $B$, respectively.
Thus, one can rewrite
$|\text{Tr}[MN]| = | \sum_i \sum_j \lambda_i \mu_j |\langle v_i|u_j\rangle|^2|$.

Once I try to rewrite the right hand-side of the inequality in a similar way, it becomes a real mess, as I cannot assume that both $A$ and $B$ are diagonalized with respect to the same basis, hence I am left with lots of inner products between basis vectors from $\{v_i\}$ and $\{u_j\}$ (under the root, which occurrs due to the definition of the absolute value of a matrix - see above).

Is there any trick, how I can prove this statement directly, or is there anything that I missed when tying my "brute force diagonalizing" approach?

I am very grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Theorem**.  For any matrix $A$,  one has that
$$
  |\text{tr}(A)|\leq \text{tr}(|A|).
  $$

*Proof*.
Considering the inner product  defined on $M_n(\mathbb C)$ by
$$
  \langle X, Y\rangle =\text{tr}(X^*Y),
  $$
one has
by the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality that
$$
  |\text{tr}(X^*Y)|\leq \text{tr}(X^*X)^{1/2}\text{tr}(Y^*Y)^{1/2}.
  $$

Using  the polar decomposition,  write $A=U|A|$, where $U$ is a unitary matrix, and set
$X=|A|^{1/2}U^*$, and $Y=|A|^{1/2}$.  Then $A=X^*Y$, so

$$
  |\text{tr}(A)|=|\text{tr}(X^*Y)| \leq
  \text{tr}(X^*X)^{1/2}\text{tr}(Y^*Y)^{1/2} =
    $$
$$ =
  \text{tr}(U|A|U^*)^{1/2}\text{tr}(|A|)^{1/2} = \text{tr}(|A|).
  $$

---

PS: The same proof can be used to show that $|\tau(A)|\leq \tau(|A|)$, for every *positive trace* $\tau$ on any $C^*$-algebra $\mathscr A$, that is, any linear functional
$$
\tau:\mathscr A \to \mathbb C,
$$
such that $\tau(A^*A)\geq 0$, and $\tau(BA)=\tau(AB)$, for every $A$ and $B$ in $\mathscr A$.